# Concatenate multiple columns in a case statement

Tags: sql-server

There is a query in which I have to concatenate 12 columns in a case statement. It would've been easier if it was 2 or 3. To be clearer, here is my query:

```
SELECT column1 
  ,column2
  ,effet_secondaire_desc = CASE WHEN [symp01] = 'y' THEN 'Pedi apeti'
                                WHEN [symp02] = 'y' THEN 'Ke plen'
                                WHEN [symp03] = 'y' THEN 'Zye jon'
                                WHEN [symp04] = 'y' THEN 'Dyare'
                                WHEN [symp05] = 'y' THEN 'Ko grate'
                                WHEN [symp06] = 'y' THEN 'Lafyev ak frison'
                                WHEN [symp07] = 'y' THEN 'Ko fe mal ak jwenti fe mal'
                                WHEN [symp08] = 'y' THEN 'Pikotman'
                                WHEN [symp09] = 'y' THEN 'Fatig'
                                WHEN [symp10] = 'y' THEN 'Tet vire/vetij'
                                WHEN [symp11] = 'y' THEN 'Vant fe mal'
                                WHEN [symp12] = 'y' THEN [symp12_desc] 
                                ELSE '~'
                            END
             .....
             ,columnx
FROM MyTable
```

[symp01] ... [symp12] are the 12 columns I want to concatenate. So the value of effet_secondaire_desc should be something like this 'Pedi apeti, Ko grate, Lafyev ak frison, ...'.

Can anyone help me with this please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like very bad database design. Multiple symptoms should be stored as multiple rows, not multiple columns. You should change that if it's not too late.

Comment: It's to late. I did not design the database. My role is just to give a daily report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    column1 
  , column2
  , effet_secondaire_desc = isnull(nullif(stuff(
     case when [symp01] = 'y' then ', Pedi apeti'                  else '' end
    +case when [symp02] = 'y' then ', Ke plen'                     else '' end
    +case when [symp03] = 'y' then ', Zye jon'                     else '' end
    +case when [symp04] = 'y' then ', Dyare'                       else '' end
    +case when [symp05] = 'y' then ', Ko grate'                    else '' end
    +case when [symp06] = 'y' then ', Lafyev ak frison'            else '' end
    +case when [symp07] = 'y' then ', Ko fe mal ak jwenti fe mal'  else '' end
    +case when [symp08] = 'y' then ', Pikotman'                    else '' end
    +case when [symp09] = 'y' then ', Fatig'                       else '' end
    +case when [symp10] = 'y' then ', Tet vire/vetij'              else '' end
    +case when [symp11] = 'y' then ', Vant fe mal'                 else '' end
    +case when [symp12] = 'y' then ', '+[symp12_desc]              else '' end
    ,1,2,''),''),'~')
  , columnx
from mytable
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works. Thanks a lot guys. I have been on this since thursday. You just saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?:

```
SELECT
...
CASE WHEN [symp01] = 'y' THEN ', Pedi apeti' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN [symp02] = 'y' THEN ', Ke plen' ELSE '' END
+ ...
END
```

And then wrap that in some logic to remove the first comma and space.